# Is it possible to access the output volume of an mp3 file?

Tags: audio

I would like to make an LED pulse using PWM, such that the LED brightness/PWM width supplied to it will vary with the volume of an MP3 file. Is there some way I can access the real time volume of the MP3 file as it plays?

Comment: not a question about the Raspberry Pi

Comment: it would depend on the player ... do research, and ask questions, in the Linux realm ... when you are able to obtain the volume datastream, then you can ask here how to vary the LED brightness .... only the LED is related to the Raspberry Pi

Comment: @jsotola perhaps more suitable for unix SE?

Comment: start here ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+mp3+visualizer&ia=web

Comment: here is a similar question ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679458/is-there-a-terminal-based-visualizer-for-linux-that-plays-background-music-from

Comment: Found what i was looking for now thanks!